# QWidget cannot display on QMainWindow instance PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I am learning PyQt5 now and tried to do something little on my own. I have made a very basic custom toolbox, which has just 6 `QPushButton`s buttons on it, which inherits from `QWidget` class.

My problem is that I can't display my toolbox on my `QMainWidow` instance. Let me show you what I did;

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class ToolBox(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        btn = [QPushButton('B', self) for i in range(6)]
        for Btn in btn:
            Btn.resize(30, 30)
        self.resize(60, 90)
        k = 0
        for i in range(6):
            btn[i].move((i%2)*30, k*30)
            k += 1 if i % 2 == 1 else 0
        self.show()

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.resize(300, 200)
        self.statusBar().showMessage('Ready!')

        exitAction = QAction(QIcon('idea.png'), 'Exit', self)
        exitAction.setStatusTip('Exit application')
        exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAction.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)

        menuBar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menuBar.addMenu('File')
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)

        t = ToolBox()
        t.move(150, 150)
        t.show() #With and without this line, it doesn't work.

        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    m = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to position your widget somewhere in the QMainWindow canvas. All you have to do is position it in the MainWindow. Just for an example, I use `setCentralWidget()` to position your QWidget.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class ToolBox(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        btn = [QPushButton('B', self) for i in range(6)]
        for Btn in btn:
            Btn.resize(30, 30)
        self.resize(60, 90)
        k = 0
        for i in range(6):
            btn[i].move((i%2)*30, k*30)
            k += 1 if i % 2 == 1 else 0

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.resize(300, 200)
        self.statusBar().showMessage('Ready!')

        exitAction = QAction(QIcon('idea.png'), 'Exit', self)
        exitAction.setStatusTip('Exit application')
        exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAction.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)

        menuBar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menuBar.addMenu('File')
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)

        t = ToolBox()
        self.setCentralWidget(t)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    m = MainWindow()
    m.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: OK! It works, but how do I change the coordinates of the widget in the main window?

Comment: This was not part of your initial question and doesn't fit your current code base. I recommend that you read this article on PyQt layouts: http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/layoutmanagement/

Comment: I recommend you look through these pyqt5 examples aswell. https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/tree/master/examples

Comment: @ham-sandwich I have the same problem as the one reported by OP. This is my [QWidget](https://github.com/muammar/mkchromecast/blob/f37b6f6bc48602f7d6336bb2d2ff018dcd6e71c6/mkchromecast/preferences.py). I can run it just fine except if I call it from my [QtWidgets.QMainWindow](https://github.com/muammar/mkchromecast/blob/f37b6f6bc48602f7d6336bb2d2ff018dcd6e71c6/mkchromecast/systray.py) (line 325). Even changing my code as you proposed , which is the version shown in the link, for me it does not work. I checked that your example is correct but no idea why in my case is not the solution.