# Can't Launch Spyder ImportError: libQt5Gui.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by PyQt5/QtWebKitWidgets.so)

Tags: anaconda, pyqt5, spyder

After reinstalling video card drivers and Cuda and Tensorflow, and getting Anaconda3, Spyder stopped working.

```
(tf27) fosa@fosa-desktop ~ $ spyder
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fosa/anaconda3/envs/tf27/bin/spyder", line 3, in <module>
    start.main()
  File "/home/fosa/anaconda3/envs/tf27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 103, in main
    from spyder.app import mainwindow
  File "/home/fosa/anaconda3/envs/tf27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 92, in <module>
    from qtpy import QtWebEngineWidgets  # analysis:ignore
  File "/home/fosa/anaconda3/envs/tf27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qtpy/QtWebEngineWidgets.py", line 26, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebPage as QWebEnginePage
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by /home/fosa/anaconda3/envs/tf27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt5/QtWebKitWidgets.so)
```

And when we check the directory we see it is there

```
(tf27) fosa@fosa-desktop ~ $ ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
```

My issue is incredibly similar to this one: [PyQt5 not finding installed Qt5 library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39129615/pyqt5-not-finding-installed-qt5-library)

But I don't seem to be getting lucky with uninstalling from pip3 or installing from apt

Linux Mint 18

Any takers? Any other system info needed?

Comment: It seems you messed with LD_LIBRARY_PATH, which broke Spyder and Anaconda too. Please stop doing that and revert to what you had before to fix all things.

Comment: Very nice, that was the problem. Had to delete two 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH' lines from ~/.bashrc that were hanging around from before and now it works.  Add your comment as an answer if you'd like me to mark it correct.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One fix is to downgrade Qt5 to Qt4 but I'm sure I had Qt5 working before..

```
conda install qt=4
```