# Problem importing PandasGUI in Docker-launched Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, docker, jupyter-notebook, pyqt5

I am trying to import PandasGUI from within Jupyter Notebook, to interact with it as is demonstrated in the demo (YouTube: [PandasGUI Demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NKXdolMxW2Y)). Here is the ImportError that was returned:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-07e0e34bb4ec> in <module>
     17 
     18 
---> 19 from pandasgui import show
     20 
     21 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandasgui/__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from pandasgui.gui import show
      2 
      3 __all__ = ["show"]

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandasgui/gui.py in <module>
      7 import pandas as pd
      8 import pkg_resources
----> 9 from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
     10 from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
     11 

ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.15' not found (required by /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.abi3.so)
```

I tried force-installing PyQt5 version 5.15 using `pip3 install PyQt5==5.15` and `pip install PyQt5==5.15`, then reinstalled PandasGUI using `pip3 install pandasgui`... which did not work.

**System Information** (that might be relevant to the issue)

- I'm using The mltooling/ml-workspace development environment, launched out of Docker.

  - [DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/r/mltooling/ml-workspace)
  - [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/ml-tooling/ml-workspace)
- Computer: Mac, running on macOS Catalina (Version 10.15.4)

---

Here are some similar issues I found, but none of them are in the context of launching PandasGUI, nor did they work:

- [Python3: ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.15' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63903441/python3-importerror-lib-x86-64-linux-gnu-libqt5core-so-5-version-qt-5-15-n)
- [[Solved] Qt_5 not defined in file libQt5Core.so.5 with link time reference](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=306738)

---

Does anyone have any suggestions?